# Creating a number where subsequest digits are greater : C++

Tags: c++, logic

I have to write a function say `numbers(int MSD,int num)` such that if I call the function as `numbers(5,4)` , it should generate all 4 digit numbers greater than 5000 where subsequent digits are greater.

e.g.

It should output

```
5678
5679
5689
5789
6789
```

That is the only possible set of 4 digit numbers where subsequent digits are greater than previous.

Similarty `numbers(3,3)` should output:

```
345
346
347
348
349
356
357
358
359
...
...
456
457
...
789
```

Hope I made my question clear. Tried a lot but I am not able to implement the logic.

Thanks

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Something of this sort first generating initial number `void displayHighers(int n) { int temp=0; int N=n; while(n != 0) { temp+=n*pow(10,N-n); n--; } cout <<"Here " << temp << endl; }` that will generate number of type `displayHighers(5)` outputs `12345` then I was trying to increment all the positions till 9 but I got lost in looping

Comment: Did you try debugging?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I was not able to get the multiple loops right.. I am still trying to solve it, but thought of asking if anyone got better logic than this - basically what I am trying to implement is `numbers(5,4)` should generate initial number as `5678` then I will loop unity position till `9` then `10th` position till `9` making all combinations with increments of all digits till `9` but I am getting lost while implementing this logic..

Comment: You didn't answer whether you debugged it or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use recursion... (or convert the code below to an iterative one)
in this example i print to the std output but you can do what ever you want with the numbers generated.

i fixed the code to match your exact request and added a naive implementation of pow.

```
int Pow(int a, int b)
{
    int res = a;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < b-1 ; ++i)
    {
        res *= a;
    }

    return res;
}

void numbersInternal(int MSD,int num,int _base)
{       
    if (num == 1)
    {
        for (int j = MSD ; j <= 9 ; ++j)
        {
           cout << _base + j << endl;    
        }
    }
    else
    { 
        for (int j = MSD ; j <= 9-num+1 ; ++j)
        {
            numbersInternal(j + 1,num-1,_base + Pow(10,num-1)*j);        
        }
    }

}

void numbers(int MSD,int num)
{    
    numbersInternal(MSD,num,0);
}
```

Comment: added the pow method in the code.